# <video src="..." autoplay></video> Не работает autoplay

Tags: html, css, видео

Есть такая разметка

> ```
> <header class="header">
>   <video class="header__video" src="../src/video/video.mp4" autoplay loop muted type="video/mp4"></video>
> </header>
> ```

```
.header {
  position: relative;
}
.header__video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Не срабатывает autoplay. 
Почему ?

Comment: Сейчас запустил в Firefox и IE11 и вот что увидел: Firefox - autoplay работает, но не сработал muted. IE11 - сработало все как надо.

Comment: В мобилках сейчас стоит запрет на автоплей со звуком